# Error "An invalid device OR an invalid constant is being used" when compile simple GX Works 2 program in FX3G PLC

Tags: plc, structured-text, iec61131-3

I have FXCPU PLC FX3G series and I create ST Structured Project in GX Works 2. The problem is I cannot loop through an array of bits. Here are my local variables.

[image]

Now this code in a program compiles with error

```
(* Do not compile! *)
FOR iCount := 0 TO 2 DO
    arOfBits[iCount] := TRUE;
END_FOR;
```

But this code works fine

```
(* Compile *)
arOfBits[1] := TRUE;
```

The compile error as follows

```
       No.: 1
    Result: Error
 Data Name: POU_01
     Class: Program compile
   Content: An invalid device OR an invalid constant is being used
Error Code: F0137
```

If that would be array of Words that would work fine in both examples. If it would be array of `STRUCT` where one property there is `bit` and another is `WORD`, then both examples would work with `WORD` but only the last example with `bit`.

The nature of the problem is that if I use Device like D100 or variable as is in example I cannot access bits but only words. To access bits, I have to use constant as array index.

Does anyone know how to address this issue?

Comment: This really seems like a limitation of this PLC or even a bug (I've seen things like this in other brands). As workarounds, apparently you tried to point directly to a memory instead of using a symbolic variable which is what I would try... if it's really important to use a array, have you considered using an `BYTE ARRAY` and saving `0` or `1` and then convert when needed?

Comment: Thank you @dwpessoa. This is what I do currently just try to access individual bits as memory address. But that does not allow me to do everything I need. For instance I have array of timers TC**. Those are bits and I need to pass that exact bit but not a bit that tells if it is ON or OFF. I mean I need to refer to it. I have just started to learn the IDE. Read only 500 pages of documentation so far. Arounf 1000 left, may be I'll yet find a solution. There is no BYTE array I can only make WORD array. But in this case, it is too big and memory only 32k.